# Unable to connect to remote server through python paramiko

Tags: python-2.7, paramiko

Sometimes back below code is working fine and i able to connect remote servers. But suddenly i'm facing below issue from today. any suggestion please.

```
import paramiko
import os
ssh_remote =paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh_remote.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
privatekeyfile = os.path.expanduser('~/.ssh/id_key')
mykey = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file(privatekeyfile, password='test123')
ssh_remote.connect('10.10.10.10', username = 'test', pkey = mykey)
```

**Error**

```
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/pkey.py", line 206, in from_private_key_file
    key = cls(filename=filename, password=password)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/rsakey.py", line 48, in __init__
    self._from_private_key_file(filename, password)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/rsakey.py", line 170, in _from_private_key_file
    self._decode_key(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/rsakey.py", line 182, in _decode_key
    raise SSHException(str(e))
paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: Could not deserialize key data.
```

**id_key**

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: DES-EDE3-CBC,89F3HUKJILLNND

MIICWwIBAAKBgQDdlatRjRjogo3WojgGHFHYLugdUWAY9iR3fy4arWNA1
KoS8kVw33cJibXr8bvwUAUparCwlvdbH6dvEOfou0/gCFQsHUfQrSDv+M
uSUMAe8jzKE4qW+jK+xQU9a03GUnKHkkle+Q0pX/g6jXZ7r1xAK5Do2kQ
+X5xK9cipRgEKwIDAQABAoGAD+onAtVye4ic7VR7V50DF9bOnwRwNXrAR
cDhq9LWNRrRGElESYYTQ6EbatXS3MCyjjX2eMhuaF5YhXBwkppwxg+EOm
Xeh+MzL7Zh284OuPbkglAaGhV9bb6/5CpuGb1esyPbYW+Ty2PC0GSZfIX
kXs76jXAu9TOBvD0ybc2YlkCQQDyMIICWwIBAAKBgQDdlatRjRjogo3Wo
KoS8kVw33cJibXr8bvwUAUparCwlvdbH6dvEOfou0/gCFQsHUfQrSDv+M
uSUMAe8jzKE4qW+jK+xQU9a03GUnKHkkle+Q0pX/g6jXZ7r1xAK5Do2kQ
+X5xK9cipRgEKwIDAQABAoGAD+onAtVye4ic7VR7V50DF9bOnwRwNXrAR
cDhq9LWNRrRGElESYYTQ6EbatXS3MCyjjX2eMhuaF5YhXBwkppwxg+EOm
Xeh+MzL7Zh284OuPbkglAaGhV9bb6/789JIJLKLLLL+Ty2PC0GSZfIXOK
kXs76jXAu9TOBvD0ybc2YlkCQQDyMIICWwIBAAKBgQDdlatRjRjogo3Wo
KoS8kVw33cJibXr8bvwUAUparCwlvdbH6dvEOfou0/gCFQsHUfQrSDv+M
uSUMAe8jzKE4qW+jK+xQU9a03GUnKHkkle+Q0pX/g6jXZ7r1xAK5Do2kQ
+X5xK9cipRgEKwIDAQABAoGAD+onAtVye4ic7VR7V50DF9bOnwRwNXrAR
cDhq9LWNRrRGElESYYTQ6EbatXS3MCyjjX2eMhuaF5YhXBwkppwxg+EOm
Xeh+MzL7Zh284OuPbkglAaGhV9bb6/99993REFSDSFDSFSD+Ty2PC0GSZ
kXs76jXAu9TOBvD0ybc2YlkCQQDy
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

**Paramiko Version - 2.4.1** and 
**python 2.7**

**OpenSSh Version**
OpenSSH_5.3p1

Comment: Any chance you tried to feed RSAKey() a **DSA** key? What does `file ~/.ssh/id_key` say?

Comment: Unable to understand.Can you please elaborate.

Comment: Are you sure `~/.ssh/id_key` is a valid RSA key file, and are you sure about the password? I got this message once when I used the wrong password/passphrase for my key.

Comment: @digitalarbeiter . Yes i'm using the correct password.. I regenerated again and facing the same problem.

Comment: @Martin Prikryl: It's look like.

-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: DES-EDE3-CBC,
MIICWwIBAAKBgQDdlatRjRjogo3WojgGHFHYLugdUWAY9iR3fy4arWNA1KoS8kVw33cJibXr8bvwUAUparCwlvdbH6dvEOfou0/gCFQsHUfQrSDv+MuSUMAe8jzKE4qW+jK+xQU9a03GUnKHkkle+Q0pX/g6jXZ7r1/xAK5Do2kQ+X5xK9cipRgEKwIDAQABAoGAD+onAtVye4ic7VR7V50DF9bOnwRwNXrARcDhq9LWNRrRGElESYYTQ6EbatXS3MCyjjX2eMhu/aF5YhXBwkppwxg+EOmXeh+MzL7Zh284OuPbkglAaGhV9bb6/5CpuGb1esyPbYW+Ty2PC0GSZfIXkXs76jXAu9TOBvD0ybc2YlkCQQDywg2R
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

Comment: @Martin Prikryl by using this command - ssh-keygen -t rsa . 

Enter file in which to save the key (/home/test/.ssh/id_rsa): id_key
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Your identification has been saved in id_key.
Your public key has been saved in id_key.pub.

Comment: When I do this, your code works just fine for me.

Comment: @Victory I hope that's not your _real_ private key, though :-D

Comment: @digitalarbeiter: Yes, i gave sample

Comment: @Martin Prikryl OpenSSH_5.3p1. I gave sample key

Comment: @Martin Prikryl yes you are correct. While im paste here, empty lines are got disappeared.

Comment: OK, so would you post the key in a correct format?

Comment: And please clean up obsolete comments above.

Comment: @Martin Prikryl  i have added the correct format and it was sample key

Comment: With Paramiko, I'm getting *"base64 decoding error: Incorrect padding"* for this key. With `ssh-keygen -p -f id_key  -P test123`, I'm getting "Bad passphrase.". When I generate a new key the way you describe, everything works.

Comment: @Martin Prikryl: sorry for late reply.. today i generated new key and facing this error [u'WARNING: Your password has expired.', u'Password change required but no TTY available.'].

not sure whether i have to change the question content or shall i raise new question?

Comment: Well, so how come it didn't work before? You were probably doing something wrong (differently that claimed). Consider deleting this question - As for the new problem - Yes it's definitely a completely new problem for a new question.

Comment: @Martin Prikryl: I followed the same steps but not sure why i'm different error today. Let me raise new question and thanks for your help and suggestions.